# Flutter TextFormField, focusNode.requestFocus works once then keyboard doesn't show

Tags: flutter, focus, autofocus

Goal: when send button is pressed, don't close the keyboard and keep it open/focused
Problem: when send button is pressed, keyboard is closed, then reopens because of focusNode.requestFocus, when send button is pressed after that, the keyboard doesn't open anymore
Looking for two options:

1. (ideal) Don't let the keyboard close when send button is pressed
2. (okay) Open keyboard no matter how many times send button is closed

Here is sample UI:

```
return Form(
  key: _formKey,
  child: Row(
    children: <Widget>[
      Expanded(
        child: TextFormField(
          focusNode: chatController.focusNode,
          // textInputAction: TextInputAction.none, // didn't help
          // onEditingComplete: () {}, // didn't help
        )
      ),

      IconButton(
        icon: const Icon(Icons.send),
        onPressed: () async {
          SystemChannels.textInput
              .invokeMethod('TextInput.hide');
          if (_formKey.currentState!.validate()) {
            await chatController.sendMessage(context);
          }
        }
      ),
    ],
  )
);
```

Here is controller:

```
late FocusNode focusNode;

@override
void onReady() async { // tried onInit as well
  focusNode = FocusNode();
  super.onReady();
}

void sendMessage(BuildContext context) async {
  // focusNode.unfocus(); // didn't help
  // focusNode2.requestFocus(); // tried to give focus to another widget and take it back, but didn't help
  final a1 = focusNode.hasFocus; // except the very first call, this is true even when focusNode.unfocus() is called

  // neither of these work the second time
  focusNode.requestFocus();
  // FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(focusNode);
}
```

I was able to trace code and when second call gets to focus manager [here](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/focus_manager.dart#L1087) this condition is always true:

```
if (hasPrimaryFocus && (_manager!._markedForFocus == null || _manager!._markedForFocus == this)) {
```

even though the keyboard is closed, and it returns without attempting to open the keyboard again

Comment: Why are you calling `SystemChannels.textInput.invokeMethod('TextInput.hide');` in send callback?

Comment: @voidvoid I feel so dumb, that was the issue, I copied this code from a sample project and never paid attention to that, thanks

Comment: Glad I could help, I thought that wasn't the only problem. Everyone makes silly mistakes sometimes :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a stray:

```
SystemChannels.textInput.invokeMethod('TextInput.hide');
```

in your `IconButton` callback, it should work after removing it.